# How to stream Select results (not String query results) from CassandraOperations?

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

Spring Data Cassandra 1.5.0 comes with a streaming API in CassandraTemplate. I'm using `spring-data-cassandra` 1.5.1. I have a code like:

```
    String tableName = cassandraTemplate.getTableName(MyEntity.class).toCql();
    Select select = QueryBuilder.select()
            .all()
            .from(tableName);
    // In real world, WHERE statement is much more complex
    select.where(eq(ENTITY_FIELD_NAME, expectedField)) 
    List<MyEntity> result = cassandraTemplate.select(select, MyEntity.class);
```

and want to replace this code with iterable or Java 8 Stream in order to avoid fetching a big list of results to memory at once.

What I'm looking for is a method signature like `CassandraOperations.stream(Select query, Class<T> entityClass)`, but it is not available.

The only available method in `CassandraOperations` accepts query string: `stream(String query, Class<T> entityClass)`. I tried to pass here a string generated by `Select` like

```
cassandraTemplate.stream(select.getQueryString(), MyEntity.class)
```

But that fails with `InvalidQueryException: Invalid amount of bind variables`, because getQueryString() returns query with question mark placeholders instead of variables.

I see 3 options to get what I want, but every option looks bad:

- Use Spring Query creation mechanism with Stream/Iterator expected return type (good only for simple queries) http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation
- Use raw CQL query and not to use `QueryBuilder`
- Call `select.getQueryString()` and then substitute parameters again via `BoundStatement`

Is there any better way to stream selection results?

Thanks.

Comment: Right now, `stream` accepts only `String` queries. You might want to have a look at `2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` which extends `stream` to accept `Statement`. Alternatively: Did you try creating a repository for `MyEntity` declaring a method `Stream<MyEntity> findByFooAndBar(String foo, String bar)`? Works also with `@Query("…")`.

Comment: @mp911de, yes, actually I'm writing a custom repository impl with method that returns Stream. But again, in this method I'm using CassandraOperations that does not allow passing Select object into stream() method.

Comment: You're not required to create a custom repo impl because Spring Data Cassandra supports returning `Stream` (as of 1.5). All the query handling/parameter binding is handled by the default repository implementation.

Comment: @mp911de, you are right. I can create query method in repository interface, and specify that it returns a Stream. That will work for simple queries, but for queries with large WHERE block a method name will be extremely long and unreadable. Or I can write raw CQL in @Query annotation, but that was the thing I was trying to avoid by using QueryBuilder. Thank you, will probably have to wait for ``2.0.0`` stable version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as of now the answer on my question is to wait until stable version of `spring-data-cassandra` `2.0.0` comes out:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/2.0.x/spring-data-cassandra/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/CassandraTemplate.java#L208